# displaying dynamic listview in jquery mobile

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I will get some data(like list of names)from the server in runtime of my mobile application. That I need to show it in a listview.

I am using JQuery Mobile to display my UI.

Please let me how to crate listview in JQM and set the data dynmically to it.

Comment: After spending 3 years here you still didn't learn how thing works? Show us what have you done? And what is your current problem? We will not do your homework for you. And do you really expect someone will help you when you never accept your question answers? You should be ashamed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### Example:

Here's a working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/9ut5c/

### Code:

#### HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>jQM Complex Demo</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1"/>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css" /> 
        <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>    
    </head>
    <body>
        <div data-role="page" id="home">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <h3>
                    Movie List
                </h3>
            </div>        
            <div data-role="content">
                <div class="example-wrapper" data-iscroll>
                    <input name="movie-title" id="movie-title" value="" type="text" placeholder="Enter Movie Title"/>            
                    <a href="#" class="ui-btn" id="search-movie">Search</a>
                    <ul data-role="listview"  id="movie-list" data-theme="a">

                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>            
        </div>
        <div data-role="page" id="headline">
            <div data-theme="a" data-role="header">
                <a href="#home" class="ui-btn-left" data-transition="slide" data-direction="reverse">Back</a>                        
                <h3>
                    Movie Info
                </h3>
            </div>        
            <div data-role="content">
                <ul data-role="listview"  id="movie-data" data-theme="a">

                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>    
    </body>
</html>
```

#### JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('pageinit', '#home', function(){      

    $(document).on('click', '#search-movie', function(){ 
        if($('#movie-title').val().length > 0) {
            var url = 'http://api.themoviedb.org/3/',
                mode = 'search/movie?query=',
                movieName = '&query='+encodeURI($('#movie-title').val()),        
                key = '&api_key=470fd2ec8853e25d2f8d86f685d2270e';        

            $.ajax({
                url: url + mode + key + movieName ,
                dataType: "jsonp",
                async: true,
                success: function (result) {
                    ajax.parseJSONP(result);
                },
                error: function (request,error) {
                    alert('Network error has occurred please try again!');
                }
            });          
        } else {
            alert('Please enter mobie title!');
        }       
    });        
});

$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#headline', function(){      
    $('#movie-data').empty();
    $.each(movieInfo.result, function(i, row) {
        if(row.id == movieInfo.id) {
            $('#movie-data').append('<li><img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"></li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Title: '+row.original_title+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Release date :'+row.release_date+'</li>');
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.popularity+'</li>');   
            $('#movie-data').append('<li>Popularity : '+row.vote_average+'</li>');                     } 
    });          
    $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');     
});

$(document).on('vclick', '#movie-list li a', function(){  
    movieInfo.id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    $.mobile.changePage( "#headline", { transition: "slide", changeHash: false });
});

var movieInfo = {
    id : null,
    result : null
}

var ajax = {  
    parseJSONP:function(result){  
        movieInfo.result = result.results;
        $('#movie-list').empty();        
        $.each(result.results, function(i, row) {
            console.log(JSON.stringify(row));
            $('#movie-list').append('<li><a href="" data-id="' + row.id + '"><img src="http://d3gtl9l2a4fn1j.cloudfront.net/t/p/w185'+row.poster_path+'"/><h3>' + row.title + '</h3><p>' + row.vote_average + '/10</p></a></li>');
        });
        $('#movie-list').listview('refresh');
    }
}
```

#### CSS:

```
.ui-content {
    padding: 0 !important;
}

.ui-listview {
    margin: 0 !important;
}

.example-wrapper, .example-wrapper div.iscroll-scroller {
    width: 100% !important;
}
```

### How everything works

- To make this example work I have used freely available **themoviedb** API framework. Basically it doesn't matter what server side link is used, principle is the same.
- AJAX is used to communicate between client and server, using JSON format
- Listview is dynamically created using response JSON data
- Be careful with dynamically created listview, it look and feel must be enhanced programatically using something like this line:

  $('#movie-data').listview('refresh');

If you need more example then take a look **[here](http://www.gajotres.net/advanced-jquery-mobile-tutorial-part-2-client-server-communication/)**.

Just